# What are the best cloth diapers for a large baby?

Tags: infant, cloth-diaper, shopping, weight

My son is 5 months old and at 21 pounds, barely fits in 13"x 20" prefolds that claim to go up to 28 pounds. The next and only size up for prefolds is 16.5"x 21". They claim to hold babies up to 40 pounds, but my son has consistently outgrown prefolds at a lower weight, so these would probably only last until 35 pounds. Realistically, he will outgrow the 16.5"x 21" before he is potty trained. We have some bum genius 4.0 in addition to the prefolds, but they only go up to 35 pounds, so they won't fit him through potty training either.

What are some cloth diaper brands that offer sizes going higher than 40 pounds?

Comment: How heavy is your baby right now? An infant usually grows rapidly in the first few months and then slows down significantly afterwards. We thought our baby would be tripling her weight by like 6 months at the rate she was growing...but nope...took a whole year...

Comment: He is almost 21 pounds. Even if his growth drops to the average pound a month, he would be close to 30 by his first birthday.

Answer (score 4):

[Greenmountain](http://www.greenmountaindiapers.com/prefolds.htm) sells diapers that come in sizes of upto 40 lbs. You can probably just get away with just the large size, but if you're more comfortable, use the extra large. If it's too big on your baby, you can fold it (that's what we did) at the top.

Are you into sewing? If so, you can also [sew your own pre-folds](http://christadovel.hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Sew-Prefold-Diapers).

Word of caution: Our daughter is 13 months now, and so far we've only needed two sizes - the newborn and then the step up. She was born 7 lbs 14 ounces. She had doubled her weight by 3 months (15 lbs). After that her weight gain slowed down considerably (crawling, walking, just a whole lot of movement) and she is 20 lbs right now. So be wary of that - your child won't be gaining weight nearly as quickly as in the beginning. It slows down a LOT - they'll be [a year old before they triple their weight](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/infant-growth/AN01654).